# How should StackDriver entries be created?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am testing out using stackdriver, and I'm curious how to set additional attributes other than the message itself. For example, I'd like to see what application or server is sending the message. Perhaps something like this:

```
message: "Hello"
tags: ["Application-1", "Server-XYZ"]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Additionally, is it suggested that a straight text message is sent, or a json struct? For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create user-defined log-based metric labels, see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom attributes by using "Structured Logging".
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging

I'm not sure which product you are running your application (such as Google App Engine Standard/Flexible, Google Cloud Functions, Google Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine), it's recommended to use JSON formatted structured log.

In the case you need to configure logging agent (in the case of GCE), you can set up the agent accordingly.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation